# Using Euler's formula for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The question that I'm working on, is asking me to solve $\sin(z) = -i$ for $z$.

When using Euler's formula

\begin{align}
\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} &= -i \\
e^{iz}-e^{-iz} &= 2  \\
e^{iz}-e^{-iz} -2 &= 0 
\end{align}

Then apparently I am supposed to substitute $a=e^{iz}$
to obtain

\begin{equation}
a^2 - 2a -1 =0.
\end{equation}

which I do not understand because when I substitute back, I find
\begin{align}
a^2 - 2a -1 = e^{i2z} - 2e^{iz} -1
\end{align}

Could someone please explain me how it is that
\begin{equation}
e^{i2z} - 2e^{iz} -1 = e^{iz}-e^{-iz} -2
\end{equation}
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they're not equal, but the left-hand side is $e^{iz}$ times the right-hand side, so one of them is zero if and only if the other one is.

Comment: Right hand side times $e^{ iz}$ does indeed verify this equation, thank you!

Comment: @Martini, you should mark the question as **Answered** if you're satisfied.